# Out of Memory Exception in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#, .net, memory, bitmap, resources

My code here is loading resources out of a .resx file from a dll. It loads the resources fine until it hits around 40 or so, then it starts throwing out of memory exceptions. Could anyone explain to me why this is happening? And also how to fix it?

EDIT:

I solved my problem by changing all projects in my solution to be 64 bit.

Thanks

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads all default resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Bitmap> LoadAllInternalResources()
    {
        List<Bitmap> Ret = new List<Bitmap>();

        #region Spades

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._50);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._46);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._12);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._38);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._34);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._30);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._26);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._22);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._18);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._14);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._10);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._6);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._2);

        #endregion Spades

        #region Clubs

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._49);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._45);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._41);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._37);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._33);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._29);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._25);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._21);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._17);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._13);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._9);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._5);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._1);

        #endregion Clubs

        #region Hearts

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._51);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._47);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._43);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._39);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._35);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._31);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._27);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._23);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._19);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._15);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._11);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._7);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._3);

        #endregion Hearts

        #region Diamonds

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._52);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._48);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._44);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._40);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._36);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._32);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._28);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._24);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._20);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._16);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._12);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._8);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._4);

        #endregion Diamonds

        #region Jokers

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._54);

        Ret.Add(MainResources.MainResources._53);

        #endregion Jokers

        return Ret;
    }
```

Comment: How large are the images?  There used to a be a really good set of 72x96 cards that could be loaded into an ImageList or from disk v easily.  That site is gone, but I am sure someone has it cached/mirrored somewhere

Comment: The images are very large, around 365K each. I could be hitting the max amount of memory allowed for a 32x program I guess. Will check on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my issue, all I had to do was change my project settings to be 64 bit, instead of 32 bit.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem so much as avoid dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine does not have enough memory to load all those bitmaps. Do you need to load them all at the same time?

Here are some ways to fix the issue:

1. Perhaps load them as you need them and discard them when you do not need them. Do this a few items at a time. `File.ReadLines` uses a similar approach. It returns an `IEnumerable` and as you traverse it, it reads one line at a time. `File.ReadAllLines` will read the entire file into memory. So if you have a file which is 4GB and each line is 50KB, `File.ReadLines` will read 50KB at a time. `File.ReadAllLines` will read the entire 4GB into memory. (These numbers are chosen arbitrarily). So on a 32bit machine, `File.ReadAllLines` will cause out of memory exception but `File.ReadLines` MAY not so long as you do not call `ToList()` on the entire enumerator.
2. You may want to have thumbnails so you can load more of them and then load the actual image when you need the high quality one.
3. Increase the RAM on your machine. (Though this is not the solution I recommend).

Comment: I do have the RAM on the machine to load the resources. It is something to do with my program.

Comment: Yes it does have to with your program and that is what I said. How big are these bitmaps and how much RAM do you have?